# Play the same saved world around the (real) world seamlessly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use Ubuntu and what I have in mind is this:

1) Create a folder in Ubuntu One to save my minecraft game
2) Make the new location the default location in minecraft.

This way, I would be able to play my world on a computer A, exit and save. 
Ubuntu One will synchronize the saved game with every computer set on my Ubuntu One account.

On computer B, I turn on minecraft, and access my previously saved game and all the new changes I made on computer A, from computer B!

With this configuration I should be able to play around the world seemlessly.

I've posted this here because my problem is not an Ubuntu problem, it's a minecraft one.

How can I configure minecraft to access this folder in Ubuntu One. Which piece of code should I change?

Comment: I don't really think that's a question you should be asking on this site. Since this website is about the game and not about network problems

Comment: I even think it's better to set up a server by yourself then.

Comment: It's not a networking problem.
It's a file configuration problem.

The networking part is solved.

Comment: But with a server I need a fixed IP address and some sort of hosting. I don't have the guarantee that the computer is turned on at home if I'm roaming.

Comment: What I want is a universal accessible in single player mode.

Comment: Well, I won't be able to answer this, I've never tried it because i got my own server

Comment: If Ubuntu One can't be configured to backup specific directories, you'll have to place a symbolic or hard link to the Minecraft save in whatever directory it *does* look in. You can't tell Minecraft to look in a different location (not without any modification, at least).

Comment: perhaps you want to try the minecraft chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk

Comment: try using symbolic links to link to the minecraft folder in ubuntu one. it might work

Comment: The symbolic link is a good idea :) I will try that.

Comment: Isn't there an option to select where Minecraft stores its (saved) data in the new launcher?

Comment: for me it only lists the location, but i'm not sure if it's the same case for others

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't test it right now (At work) but I believe Minecraft stores its configuration data (and world data) in "$HOME/.minecraft".

If you replace that directory with a symlink to a folder in the Ubuntu One folder it should use that new folder to store it's data, if you do the same at a different computer the game shouldn't know the difference.

Comment: Aah sorry, noticed the comments already mentioned this to late, still, I think it should work.

Comment: FWIW, I use the same technique with [Dropbox](http://db.tt/HIHEqNu) and it works great too.

Comment: @Brant — And it works a whole lot better since the region format conversion.  Syncing dozens of files makes Dropbox much happier than syncing tens of thousands of files!

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbolic link to the Ubuntu One folder, using:

```
ln -s /path/to/ubuntu/one /path/to/minecraft/folder
```

Then make sure you sync properly and then it should work.